# Setting SupportActionBar subtitle multiline

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, multiline, subtitle

I have the following setup:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:subtitleTextAppearance="@style/TitleTextStyle"
        app:theme="@style/ActionBarStyle.Light"/>
```

and

```
<style name="TitleTextStyle">
    <item name="android:maxLines">2</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

and

```
getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle( targetString );
```

the `@textAllCaps` is applied, but `@maxLines` is ignored (I tried also `@minLines).

How to enable multiline text in subtitle?

TIA

UPDATE:

I added the code into the `onStart`:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    try{
      Field field = Toolbar.class.getDeclaredField( "mSubtitleTextView" );
      field.setAccessible( true );
      subtitleTextView = (TextView)field.get( toolbar );
      subtitleTextView.setSingleLine( false );
      subtitleTextView.setMaxLines( 2 );
      subtitleTextView.setEllipsize( TruncateAt.END );
    }catch( Exception e ) {
      Logg.e( this, "", e );
    }
}
```

the problem is now, that the ellipsize values are applied, but `setMaxLines()` call is ignored...

UPD2:

`setSingleLine( false )` did the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, `maxLines` is not a part of `TextAppearance` so changing it will not affect the subtitle appearance. Moreover, there's no *legal* way to access `Toolbar.mSubtitleTextView`, but after setting a subtitle text you can access it via reflection and change its appearance as you wish.

**UPDATE**:

That's how you can access `mSubtitleTextView` via reflection.

```
public class SubtitleAccessor {
    private static final Field sSubtitleTextViewField = getSubtitleTextViewField();

    private static Field getSubtitleTextViewField() {
        try {
            Field field = Toolbar.class.getDeclaredField("mSubtitleTextView");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            return field;
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException exception) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static TextView getSubtitleTextView(Toolbar toolbar) {
        if (sSubtitleTextViewField == null) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            return (TextView) sSubtitleTextViewField.get(toolbar);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException exception) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: actually I want to set the text only programmatically, so reflection or alike would do

Comment: how exactly can I access the subtitle's `textView` via reflection? what would be the id of it?

Comment: @injecteer I added a code sample to the answer. You cannot find `mSubtitleTextView` by id because it's created at runtime and doesn't have and id. So the best thing you can do besides rethinking your UI, or writing your own `Toolbar` class, or using a custom view instead of title and subtitle is accessing `Toolbar`'s private fields directly via reflection.

Comment: Although I ended up with single-lined subtitle with ellipsizing, as 2 lined subtitle looks ugly, but your answer gave valuable tips on the topic

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add:

```
<item name="android:singleLine">false</item>
```

If it doesn't work, you may try to use a custom view:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.your_layout_file);
```

Where `R.layout.your_layout_file` is your custom layout designed the way you want it.

Comment: what about support-actionbar?

Answer (score -2):

To use the Toolbar and the **Appcompat 21**, you have to use an ActionBarActivity and use:

```
((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("About");
```

Comment: Hi, please read and understand the question, before answering. Thanks.